# Simple solving equation for a variable.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Looking to get some clarification on how the following equation was solved for variable $N$,

$$rN-aN(N-b)^2 = 0 $$

The three solutions that were found were,

$$N= 0, b + \sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}, b - \sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}$$

Comment: $N=0$ is an obvious solution. After simplifying by $N$, you get an easy quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume $\frac{r}{a} \geq 0$.

The equation
$$
rN-aN(N-b)^2 = 0
$$
is equivalent to
$$
N (r-a(N-b)^2) = 0
$$
Now, if the product of two numbers is $0$, then one of the two numbers must be $0$. Thus either $N=0$ (first solution) or
$$
r-a(N-b)^2=0
$$
This last equation is equivalent to
$$
\frac{r}{a} = (N-b)^2
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\pm \sqrt{\frac{r}{a}} = N-b
$$
or
$$
b \pm \sqrt{\frac{r}{a}} = N
$$
Hence $N = b + \sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}$ and $N = b - \sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}$ are two more solutions.

There are no more solutions because what we did was exhaustive.

Comment: thanks for your solution it was very clear

Comment: @fr14 You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

writing your equation in the form $$N(r-a(N-b)^2)=0$$ thus we get $$N=0$$ or
$$r-a(N-b)^2=0$$ and from here we get
$$\frac{r}{a}=(N-b)^2$$ and if $$\frac{r}{a}\geq 0$$ we have $$\sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}=|N-b|$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Factoring out an $N$, we have

$$N\left(r-a(N-b)^2\right)=0$$

This is clearly $0$ if $N=0$. Assuming $N\neq0$, we divide by $N$ and obtain

$$r-a(N-b)^2=0\implies r=a(N-b)^2\implies \frac{r}{a}=N^2-2bN+b^2$$

Getting everything on the LHS, we have

$$N^2-2bN+b^2-\frac{r}{a}=0$$

Solving this with the quadratic formula, we get the results that you have.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Observe $$rN-aN(N-b)^2$$ factorizes into $$(N)(r-a(N-b)^2).$$ If this expression is equal to $0,$ by the zero product property, either $N=0,$ or  $(r-a(N-b)^2)=0,$ what are the roots to latter  case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out $N$:

$$N(r-a(N-b)^2)=0.$$

Then $N=0$ is obviously a solution. The other two solutions are found from solving the quadratic equation $$r=a(N-b)^2.$$

There are only three solutions since the original expression is a polynomial of degree three.